# Extracting the area code, first 3 and last 4 digits from an input telephone number in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

So, I've got to input the telephone number in `(333) 333-3333` format, and have to extract the area code, and the first 3 and last 4 digits from it in visual basic. How to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Beginners are welcome, but we expect a certain amount of effort to be expended on attempting to solve your own problem prior to a question being posted. We dont write code for you although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.

Answer (score 0):

Split it on `() -`:

```
Dim num = "(333) 333-3333"
Dim bits = num.Split("() -".ToCharArray())
```

Now you have bits as an array with the 3 things you wanted. Your title said last 4, your body said last 3. If you want last3, i'll leave it as an exercise for you (hint: Substring)